A new cradle: The best place to kickstart civilization
In this world, a group of experts from our world were thrown to the past by unknown forces. Exactly 12,000 years back. To go back to our world, they need to kickstart the industrial revolution as soon as possible. Even if it takes a couple generations and they are already six feet under, when the industrial revolution begins they will be brought back here. They could only take one thing: a magic computer with all the collective knowledge of humanity, compiled, organized and with zero energy requirements.
But the focus of this question is more limited. Where should the  unknown forces send them? Where could they find enough minerals, future crops and livestock, along with proper climate? Basically, what is the best place to kickstart civilization?

How many of them are there?

No matter where they are sent, a critical aspect is that the environment where they land will change. 12,000 years ago is right when the Younger Dryas happens which is spread over several hundred years. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Younger_Dryas

12,000 years ago the Sahara Desert was lush and populated. In fact, a lot of deserts were wet that long ago. I can't find easy research as to what deserts existed 12000 years ago, but they certainly did. My point? This is a ridiculous moving target - especially as nearly any continental location between the tropics of cancer/capricorn will do. There's no single right answer here. VTC:Needs More Focus.

how big is the group, a dozen will struggle just to survive, a thousand could conceivable restart civilization.

At that time frame is prior to the domestication of almost all plants and animals. That represents an enormous obstacle In terms of density of people which impacted kickstart speed.

Just to clarify - could they bring what they happened to have on them when abducted, like clothes and shoes, or were they arriving truly naked on site with a magic computer?  If they come without shoes that may actually influence selection of the terrain!

It does not really matter all that much where they land, provided it is not too inhospitable; just about any nice warm temperate region will do. Italy, for example. Southern France. Anatolia. Northern India. Southern China. Etc.
Because the heavy lifting is to get to the Late Antiquity level of technology. At that point, they have iron, they have bronze, they have ships; aided by their portable super-encyclopedia they can make cannon, wire, whatever. With Late Antiquity technology they can go wherever they want and extract whatever resources they need; it's not as if the Stone Age locals will be able to do anything much about it.
The major requirement is to have sufficiently many of the stranded explorers. One or two or a dozen won't do. They need sufficiently many people to be able to survive for enough time to establish some domesticated crops, and then to go around and enslave enough volunteer labor force so that they themselves won't have to scratch the dirt to grow their own food.

"...enslave enough volunteer labor force..." I don't think that enslaved people can be described as "volunteers".  More to the point, there's not enough of them - worldwide population 12 k years ago isn't enough to sustain anything approaching the conditions required to create the Industrial Revolution, even if they were concentrated in a tiny area.

The big concern with traveling to get what you want will actually be the risk of disease much less so than violence.  They won't have nearly the infrastructure for pharmaceuticals for a while and 12000 years is a significant evolutionary time span for microbes; so, our immune systems will likely take pathogens from other humans about as well as the Native Americans took smallpox.

they are going to have a hard time making most of that stuff since they do't have agriculture to feed themselves. there is only a few things that can be domesticated to produce a stable diet, and even fewer produce a lot of food prior to domestication.

12000 years ago was the arse end of the Ice Age.
Almost all the prime land was taken at that time by people a whole lot tougher and meaner than your chaps. They'd be wiped out in short order if all they could take was a computer.
Send them somewhere isolated and uninhabited like New Zealand with enough population to go it alone. Hunter gatherers are no joke if you encroach on them.
New Zealand pretty much has everything you would need in terms of natural resources and no humans at that time. There's no particularly dangerous animals, poisonous critters etc,. to contend with. Just a lot of food running around that doesn't know humans are dangerous. Start them at the top of the North Island where it's warmer and they have the whole country to gather resources from with 8-9000 years before anyone else will arrive there.

Also of note, New Zealand has abundant coal, oil, and high quality iron ore which are the big prerequisites from a raw materials stand point for industrialization.  It means you can mass produce and power machines and you can produce synthetic polymers like rubber and plastic.  In fact it has a very diverse and differentiated geology giving you all sorts of useful raw materials in close proximity.

@Nosajimiki yep, and no particularly dangerous animals, poisonous critters etc,. to contend with. Just a lot of food running around that doesn't know humans are dangerous.

NZ also lacks anything you can use for a staple crop, so you better start breeding programs for those animals because you will not have anything in the way of agriculture.

@john they had fern roots, cabbage trees etc,.. The Maori managed quite well for over 1000 years. You don't need breeding programs, you won't run out of fauna for a long long time, and last time I was there I got enough seafood in a couple of hours to feed me for a week out of one trip to the coast. I would have had a LOT more but was choosy and only took the best stuff.

@Kilisi I said staple crops, the maori brought there staple crops with them, they are not native. A large number of humans can strip land quickly and you need a lot of human to support technology. great you got a bunch of seafood with modern equipment, now do it with a stick you cut with a sharpened rock, with the knowledge one cut on your feet in the ocean could mean your life.  then figuire out how to preserve that seafood, and do it again tomorrow, and the next day.

@john what makes you think they brought their crops? They tried to plant taro and it failed. The only outside crop they had was kumara. Fern roots (their staple) and cabbage trees are NZ native plants. Preserving food is easy if you know how. Smoke it dry it, stick it in fat etc.. My modern equipment was a screwdriver to prise the paua up with and my underpants for modesty. Nothing else was needed. I don't have diving gear, wouldn't have a clue how to use it.

Kumara a major staple crop, also uwhi, also taro only failed in the long term, https://www.auckland.ac.nz/en/news/2019/04/09/new-fossil-evidence-claims-first-discovery-of-taro-in-mori-garde.html#:~:text=Previous%20archaeological%20evidence%20favoured%20kumara,such%20as%20p%C5%ABh%C4%81%20and%20watercress. fern root is low in nutrition and high in labor, not a great staple crop escpecialy by itself.

@John I don't get your point, you can read other sources and get fern as the most important staple, seaweed, berries, etc,. keep looking and you'll get the 13th tribe of Israel eventually and red headed Europeans blown off course. I'd survive just fine without kumara. Try growing taro or uwhi in the South Island or even Wellington and see what happens. Not worth the effort yeilds are ridiculous.

I'm not argueing about which was the maori most important crop, I am argueing about which crops can support industrialization, you need high yeild easily storable crops, abundant biodiviersity won't survive intense human consumption, most of the places that have large cities today used to be super plentiful, then industrializing cultures stripped them, in new yourk shelfish used to be so common you could litterly shovel them out of the bays to sell as cheap food, the english fish population was so high it was one of the worlds major exporter, abundant natural food is not enough

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

@John you don't make sense. Sure you need different things when you're approaching that level and demographic, no argument on that. But you don't need them on the way there. The question is about where to Kickstart the people. PNG, Australia, South East Asia etc are all within easy reach long before you get to Industrial tech. Start somewhere easy and sustainable so you don't all die and have plenty of leisure time to work in, expand out to grab whatever resources you need as your tech rises.

In a few years you can deal with the hunter gatherers from a position of overwhelming strength, with sail boats, projectile weapons, armour, explosives etc,. Take whatever you want and retreat back where they can't follow. Surviving and being productive in those first years is the main problem to solve.

Ok so your only looking at it as an early point before becoming a colonizer, that makes a lot more sense. you might want to add that to the answer. of course that means the coal, oil and rubber dont matter much.

@John they matter, while a few people are feeding the whole group, others have the leisure to work on the tech. Eg,. 20 people, 2 get the food, 18 do other things. Instead of 20 people struggling to stay alive in a hostile and dangerous environment and achieving little else while attrition pares them down.

coal, oil and rubber don't matter if you intend to leave the island before they can be utilized, either they are staying and they can't make enough food, or they are leaving and coal oil and rubber don't matter becasue they have left befofe they have the numbers to support the tech to utilize them.

@John why would they leave, you go to the shop to get stuff, but you go back home after. They'd just send out task forces if it was me in charge.

Natives shouldn't be a big problem.  Explorers occasionally found hostile tribes, yes, but by and large they had friendly first relations until they tried to take over.  The time travelers have no reason to do that - they have countless gifts to offer.  Merely singing with modern musical scales would get you a fruit basket.  Show them where to find ocher and what to do with it.  Give them a loom.  As long as your expedition isn't infested with slave-taking monsters, you'll have the native population adoring you.  Complex language is an asset too, and one day they'll join your culture.

@MikeSerfas New Zealand had no humans 12000 years ago. So no natives.

New World, perhaps Peru, perhaps Cuzco.  Your people don't have the infrastructure to make most antibiotics or vaccines.  Some of the historical origins of pathogens are still remarkably uncertain - I think there's a case for saying some malaria strains might have made it to the New World before the European contact - but 12,000 years ago, your odds were good.  Only a very few individuals had made the crossing and they brought few pathogens with them.  In the Old World you'd be dealing with malaria, yellow fever, Black Death and more.
After that, pick out some coal deposits and iron ore deposits for another nasty old Industrial Revolution.  I'll say Peru - you have both resources, coastline, forests, rainfall, a wide range of elevations and conditions, and you're near the center of where a future Incan Empire was highly successful.
I'm not sure you would like to go to the high altitude of Cuzco to start your capital in a proven location.  But the high altitudes have more gold deposits.  Depending on your opinions about pre-Clovis settlement of the New World, humans in Peru might be hard to find at that time, or not.  There were definitely some that had arrived nearby, all the way up at 13,000 feet above sea level to hunt large game.  But they could have left hundreds of years before you arrive - there are no guarantees.  If human neighbors can be found, assuming they have the same aesthetics as most folk, they can probably be convinced to trade and do most things you need doing while you work out the basics of smelting, because you'll be the only ones who know how to turn the nuggets that are free for the taking in many rivers, into wearable works of art.  Just make sure they don't see how you do it!

the biggest problem with the new world is no long lasting grain and nothign to pull a plow, food comes first. corn had ot be bred a long time before it was very productive.

@John - they asked for industry, not sacher torte.  There was enough food to sustain the Incas.  Including the ever-versatile potato, though I'd be a little leery of toxins in ancient wild cultivars.  But these are just a few people in virgin wilderness - if they can dodge the dire wolf and the saber-tooth, they'll feast on abundant game with little fear of man.

thats my point it was enough to feed the incas after thousands of years of selective breeding, and for industrialization they need to feed a lot more than the entire incan empire.

They're supposed to industrialize using their prior knowledge after "a couple generations".  If 100 people have 10 children each for two generations, there should still be some giant sloths for them to hunt from their shiny new helicopters once they get them in the air.

or more than half those children starve because of food insecurity, survival rates for offsping are around 1 in five without antibiotics and good nutrition, you need food before you industrialize not after, you need large populations to produce and support technology.  10000 people is not enough peole to get you helicopters, esspecially when most of them will need to spend all their time gathering food.

Oh come on, clearly that wasn't what I was suggesting.  They're sloths.  They aren't that hard to kill with a spear (I can safely say from a great distance).  The only risk is driving them extinct before you can hunt them with all the modern conveniences.

Or human will hunt them all a few years, since they had an abysmally slow reproduction rate, hence how they went extinct in the first place. easy to kill means you wipe them out fast.

12,000 years ago it was about the end of last Ice Age, still very cold and with very limited "technology" (late paleolitic/mesolitic) no agriculture or animal domestication (just dogs were domesticated at that time).
OTOH Homo Sapiens was already spread all over the world.
I would suggest a relatively warm place with access to sea and metal deposits (firstly copper, then others).
I would suggest either Greece or South America (Andes region).
From climate point of view Greece would be better, for metals Andes are superior.
Notice you would need several hundred "colonists" to survive the first few years; expect at least one half of whoever arrives to die in the first winter.
Main problem is "experts", even if they fancy as survival experts would be weak as kittens in an untamed world (from some studies on footprints seems an "average hominid" of that age could run loops around Usain Bolt).
Also stock provisions would be needed to go past the first few days, before "experts" could train themselves to become efficient hunter/gatherers.
To learn how efficiently build and use even the simplest "stone age tools" is not something that can be done in days.
Most likely you should drop a well equipped group that would easily survive while supplies last giving them time to adapt before their irreplaceable stuff gives away (from bullets to tents and axes to knives ALL would wear relatively quickly).
Even "Rambo-like" survivalists would have very hard time if dropped naked and with no provisions, even in the "best places on Earth".

note shorline 12,000 years ago, won't stay shoreline for long. see doggerland.

Frame Challenge: Can't be Done (Meaningfully)
10,000BC is before humans domesticated anything except dogs, so there's probably not a lot your travelers can do to alter history.
Domestication is not a knowledge thing, it's a process. Animals and plants must be bred to change their genes and this is unlikely to occur on a short enough time scale for your time-travelers to do anything useful.
As an example, sheep don't naturally produce wool in meaningful amounts. They were originally kept for meat and milk, and mutated to produce wool later. So knowing that wool can exist won't allow your time-travelers to produce wool!
Similarly, the horse was domesticated ~3,500BC, but the chariot didn't exist until closer to 2,200 BC - which is coincidentally when a mutation occurred in the horse genome that increased the resilience of the disks in their spine. It's possible that the horse was used for meat and pulling slow moving wagons for over a thousand years before they were useful in warfare, because the mutations needed to support that hadn't happened yet.
So it may be that the best your time-travelers can do to jump start the industrial revolution is to leave the computer for their great-great-great[...]-great-grandchildren to use thousands of years later once domestication of key plants and animals has occurred!
So Maybe Southern Caucasus
The center of early domestication efforts was Central Asia - grains in the Levant, sheep and goats in what is today Iran, and horses just north of the Black Sea. (This is spread over like 4,000 years, mind you.)
So a central location with access to those technologies early in their development might be modern Armenia or Georgia.
Your time-travelers would start the transition from neolithic hunter-gatherers to bronze age farmers, set up a religion to worship and read from the magic computer, and then die, safe in the knowledge that they've brought the timeline for the industrial revolution forward a couple thousand years. (as long as the computer doesn't get smashed by some revolutionary, or lost in a flood or something.)

The good thing about being an industrial society is that you do not need animals for anything other than food.
